# Does symlinking a file change how the file is parsed in php?

Tags: php, class, directory, centos, symlink

I have a php application that relies on several classes to function properly. If I take one of the application's class files

```
/my/folder/class.php
```

then move it somewhere else

```
mv /my/folder/class.php /my/other/folder/class.php
```

then in its place inside of

```
/my/folder/
```

I create a symlink to it called class.php via

```
ln -s /my/other/folder/class.php /my/folder/class.php
```

I would expect my application to be unaffected, but instead this is breaking it. I know the symlink is valid since at the command line I can do

```
nano /my/folder/class.php
```

and everything looks as I would expect it to. Am I missing something fundamental about the behavior of symlinks, and/or how apache or php processes them? Is it changing the working directory or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`? I can not figure out why this would have any affect on my application.

I am using Apache server in CentOs.

Thanks!

Comment: "breaking" how? (not 'bad' i hope :-))

Comment: WSOD (white screen of death). The file is included with "require_once" so it may not be being found?

Comment: don't 'guess' the error, turn on error display and checking, then you will see the error

Comment: Does your web server have permissions to read the file where it is symlinked from?

Comment: How about in .htaccess `Options +FollowSymLinks` ?

Comment: somehow something I did corrupted the file the symlink was targetting so it was slightly different than the original. I opened it in a text editor and saw it had some garbage characters that were breaking the script. ughhh. had nothing to do with the symlink. thanks for your patience guys.

Comment: Most general purpose filesystem operations, e.g. fopen, file_get/put_contents will be unaware they're dealing with a symlink and the input/output they do will be done on the TARGET of the link, not the link itself. This includes things like `stat()`. There's various dedicated functions which deal with the linkfile instead of its target, e.g. `lstat()`.

Comment: I fixed the corrupted character and got an error message
ERROR: require_once(): Failed opening required 'class.xxxxxxx.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') 
I changed the name to xxxx cuz I don't want to post it. So...some directory or relative path HAS changed it looks like. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference would be if you are using require_once or include_once and you are mixing the symlink path with the real file path.  In this instance, the X_once is going to think those files are different and load it twice (which will of course cause problems if you define any classes or functions).

Would probably need an actual error message to guess any further.